# WSO2 Composite Application-unable to create .car file

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

When i start with an ESB project and create the Endpoints, Sequences, proxy services and then try to do a Composite Application it will generated poml.xml file. But when i try to create the Archive(.car) it will not be generated. Can anyone please help me out with this? It would be grateful.
Eclipse : kepler
wso2esb-4.8.1

Comment: How do you try to create the .car file? Do you have an exception? Can you show the pom.xml file of the compositeApplication.